# nodejs events.js:141 unhandled error event ETIMEDOUT

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, events, heroku

I have a Heroku server with node.js and express that pings a website's API every second. This works fine for hours at a time, but every once in a while I'll get this error:

```
2018-01-10T02:19:28.579566+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:141
2018-01-10T02:19:28.579578+00:00 app[web.1]:       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2018-01-10T02:19:28.579579+00:00 app[web.1]:       ^
2018-01-10T02:19:28.579581+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-01-10T02:19:28.579582+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 45.60.11.241:443
2018-01-10T02:19:28.579583+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)
2018-01-10T02:19:28.579584+00:00 app[web.1]:     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:930:20)
2018-01-10T02:19:28.579585+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1078:14)
2018-01-10T02:19:28.684990+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Sometimes the error is ETIMEDOUT but sometimes it's other things (can't remember right now).

Some other post I read made me think maybe this is a problem?

```
app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log("Node app is running at localhost:" + app.get('port'))
})
```

Or maybe it's the part inside the API call loop?

```
try 
{       
    async.series([
        function(callback) { 
            apiQuery( callback, method, params);
        },
    ], function(error, results) { 
        console.log(results)
    });
}
catch(e)
{
    console.log("something went wrong!")
}
```

Not sure why the try catch isn't catching the error if it's this.

Maybe it's how I'm starting the loop?

```
runLoop()

//start looping the api data pulls
function runLoop() {
    setInterval(apiLoop, 1000)
}
```

Would it be better to have apiLoop call itself in the callback function? Or would that create nested functions that keep using increasingly larger memory?

Here is the api call code:

```
function apiQuery( callback2, method, params ) 
{
    if ( ! params ) params = [];
    var host_name = 'www.host.com';
    var url = '/Api/' + method;

        if ( params ) url += "/" + params.join('/');
        var options = {
            host: host_name,
            path: url,
        };
        callback = function(response) {
            var str = '';
            response.on('data', function (chunk) {
                str += chunk;
            });
            response.on('end', function () {
                return callback2(null, str);
            });
        }
        https.request(options, callback).end();
}
```

Comment: which part of the code ping the website?

Comment: sorry, forgot to put that part. I just edited it to include the api query code at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe ETIMEOUT is caused by the website's server, anyway you can catch the error

```
const req = https.request(options, callback)

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});

req.end();
```

Comment: Ok cool! I'll try that out and see if I get the error again. Just a quick question: did you make req a const just for performance purposes or is it necessary?

Comment: Just because make sense the use of `const`. It's not necessary and doesn't make a lot of difference imho.